# This while loop for my sorting algorithm doesn't seem to exit, why?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I am coding in javascript and am trying to make a sorting algorithm, and my while loop doesnt seem to exit, anybody know why?

```js
let sort = true
let length = 0
let i = 1
function multiSort(n) {
    length = n.length-1
    while (sort=true) {
        sort = false
        if (n[i]>n[i+1]) {
            [n[i],n[i+1] = n[i+1],n[i]]
            i += 1
            sort=true
            if (i = length) {
                i = 1
            }
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
    return n
}
console.log("Final Product: ", multiSort([3,2,5,1,4]), " Iterations: ", i)
```

Comment: `sort=true` is always true, since you assign true to sort - did you mean to do a comparison?

Comment: Your condition for `i` also needs to be updated to use comparison `===` (or just `==`) : `i = length` (and double-check your swapping syntax: `[n[i],n[i+1] = n[i+1],n[i]]`)

Comment: = is an assignment operator. == or === will compare values. You should read about this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#assignment_operators

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple problems here.

As mentioned your using javascript incorrectly. You should spend some time learning about how operators and comparisons work. You can read about them here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#assignment_operators

1. Your while statement will never be false.
2. `n[i+1]` in your compare statement can be undefined so will be false when it shouldn't be checked.

I have re-written your algorithm using a for loop instead of a while loop since we get a free iterator when we set up the loop.

```js
// We keep track of the iterations outside of the function
let iterations = 0

function multiSort(n) {
    iterations++
    
    // We set sort to false, if our conditions are not met we won't need to keep sorting
    let sort = false
    
    // Loop through every item in the array
    for(let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        let next = n[i+1]
        // If the current item is larger than the next swap their positions. We also have to check for undefined here since the end of the array can't compare to anything.
        if(n[i] > next && next !== undefined) {
            // Set sort to true since at least one item need to be sorted. This will not be set if all items in the array are in sequence.
            sort = true
            n[i+1] = n[i]
            n[i] = next
        }
    }
    
    // If we set sort to true re-run everything with the current array.
    if(sort) {
        multiSort(n)
    }
    
    // return the final array
    return n
}

console.log("Final Product: ", multiSort([3,2,5,1,4]), " Iterations: ", iterations)
```